# Wrong behaviour of "sort -u"?

Tags: 17.10, sort, gnu

[updated 12.11]

I found a temporary solution for this.

`LC_ALL=C sort -u`

from bugreport [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?11004)

`sort` will get info from `LC_ALL` or `LANG`,

My default is empty for `LC_ALL`, but `zh_CN.UTF-8` for `LANG`.
If `en_US.UTF-8` is set for `LANG`, same problem will occur.

I won't dig for more. But it seems like that incorrect encoding method is used for `sort`.

Thanks a lot for @GeorgeUdosen.

---

[updated 12.11]
Test on other systems:

```
Distribution              Sort_Version      Result
====================================================
ubuntu 17.10 (laptop)     gnu sort 8.26     Wrong
ubuntu 16.04 (desktop)    gnu sort 8.5      Wrong
centos 7                  gnu sort 8.22     Correct
centos 6                  gnu sort 8.6      Wrong
Max OSX                   2.3-Apple (99)    Correct
```

---

everyone,

I have some work to do with my Chinese Corpus.
One of them is to build a Chinese character list.

Here is the problem. I got some characters (Chinese punctuations) below:

`“
”
、
。
《
》
！
（
）
，
：
？`

if I try to use `sort -u`, I only got symbols below:

`“
”
、`

---

`sort version is 8.26, on ubuntu 17.10 with everything up to date.`

full operation record: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/9X0RV0sN)

characters above could be downloaded at: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/b49rLGX0)

Comment: Please make sure these are actually typed from the keyboard! When I do so it sorts ok...

Comment: Yes, I tried to type them all. They are all Chinese characters  (SBC case, punctuations) which could be typed.

Comment: **You tried** or **You typed**?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, they are Chinese punctuations (SBC case). I typed them all with the same result.

Comment: Have you compared `locale` (language settings) at all OSes you checked? Try running `LC_ALL=C sort -u`, because some characters (in some character sets) have the same sorting order and `sort -u` returns only one of each group. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/104318 for broader description.

Comment: @michal Yeah, this is the reason!   I just figured it out before read your post.        By setting `LC_ALL=C`, coded bytes has been compared, so we got the correct result.       From 
 http://agentzh.org/misc/code/coreutils/sort.c.html#L2702,  set `LC_ALL=C` equal to set `LC_COLLATE=1`.

Comment: @EliahKagan ,  thanks~ I'm told two days for acceptance...

Answer (score 1):

use

`LC_ALL=C sort -u`
or
`LC_COLLATE=C sort -u`

to force the [compare function](http://agentzh.org/misc/code/coreutils/sort.c.html#L2702) in `sort` to compare memory bytes for correct result.